# Change default save file type on Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When Code::Blocks creates a new empty file (`Ctrl+Shift+N`) it always uses the `.c` extension. If I want to change the extension to `.cpp` I have to type that in manually each time.

This is annoying when I forget to add the extension and accidentally create a '.c' file.

Since I am lazy, is there a way for the file type to default to `.cpp` (or any other type that is wanted)?

Comment: Long-winded, but Use File|New..|File - you eventually get to choose a .cpp extension.. Probably not too difficult to add a configuration option to the C::B source, which I've always found quite easy to navigate. Or post a suggestion on the C::B forums.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this stupid solution all day long but unfortunately, nothing was found. It seems to be the default setting need to be changed whenever you want to use any template from any project.

- Go to `Program Files/CodeBlocks/share/CodeBlocks/templates/wizard/console/cpp`
- You'll see file `main.cpp`, what you need is to just edit the contents of this file to your default code and save it.